# Custom multitoc (col separation and line below section title)

Tags: multicol, tocloft

I need to create a customized multitoc and so far I'm pretty close. Two things I can't figure out are

1. how can I change the spacing between the two toc columns (needs to be bigger)
2. How can I add a line below a section title (from the number to the page)

If someone with a little more experience in customizing TOC may could shed some light into this?

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
% tocloft configuration for custom table of contents
% As this interferes with the hyperref setup, the link styling has to be done local or links have to be removed for the toc.
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Large\bfseries\color{blue}} 
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfont}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecpagefont}{\color{blue}}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % remove dots from toc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{A}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it for me using

`\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace{3pt}{\color{blue}\hrule}\vspace{3pt}}`

this gives me a horizontal line after the section titles.

[image]

For the column separation I ended up setting the `\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}`, as the rest of my document is single column, this works fine.